# Splitting Variable of integer into 2 Set

Tags: microcontroller, c

I have actually 2 issue in code.

1) variable declaration. I have declare variable
unsigned int Top_Display=0;
if assign Top_Display=0123 display shows 0083
if assign Top_Display=123 display shows 0123
Some of the variable it take properly and some are not. if i assign value Top_Display=0129 it gives error digit is out of range.

2)i have created 1ms timer interrupt . every 1ms i am increment msec . i am getting wrong calculation for displaying Msec to sec. other paramter it showing well. somewhere the conversion is affected

1S=1000ms
60S=1Min
60M=1H

```
      unsigned char LED_MS_Flag=0;
    unsigned char LED_SeMi_Flag=0;
    unsigned char LED_HM_Flag=0;
unsigned char Main_Flag=0;
unsigned char j=0;
 int Bottom_Value=0;
 unsigned int Top_Display=0;
unsigned int Float_Value;
unsigned int InG_value;
unsigned char LEDBuffer_1[8];

unsigned int Hour=0;
unsigned int Min=0;
unsigned int Sec=0;
unsigned int MSec=0;
const unsigned char DISPTABLE[28] = {0x03,0x9F,0x25,0x0D,0x99,0x49,0x41,0x1F,0x01,0x09,0x11,0x83,0x31,
                                      //0  //1  //2  //3  //4  //5  //6  //7  //8  //9  //A  //U  //P
                                     0xD1,0xE3,0x89,0x63,0xE1,0xF5,0xC1,0x61,0x71,0xF3,0xFD,0xD5,0x85,0xFF,0X43};
                                      //h  //L  //Y  //C  //t  //r  //b   //E //F  //I  //-  //n //d  //blank //G
unsigned char Blink_Count=1;
unsigned char Converted_Value;
unsigned int Top_Value=0;
unsigned char EEPROM_Write_Flag=0;

unsigned char EEPROM_Read_Flag=1;
unsigned int Result;

void Process_RUN_MODE() {
    if(EEPROM_Read_Flag==1) {
        //READ_EPROM();
        EEPROM_Read_Flag=0;
    }
    Top_Display=(int)1123;

    LED_MS_Flag=1;
    if(LED_MS_Flag==1) {

        LED_HM_Flag=0;//min_Hour Flag
        LED_SeMi_Flag=0;// Sec & min FLag
        LED_MS=1;
        LED_SS=0;
        LED_HM=1;
        Dissect(Top_Display);
        DelayMs(10);
        Dissect_2(Bottom_Value);
    } else if(LED_HM_Flag==1) {
        LED_SeMi_Flag=0;//sec & min flag
        LED_MS_Flag=0;//Sec_ms Flag
        LED_HM=0;
        LED_MS=1;
        LED_SS=1;
        Dissect(Top_Display);
        Dissect_2(Bottom_Value);
    } else if(LED_SeMi_Flag==1) {
        LED_HM_Flag=0;//min_Hour Flag
        LED_MS_Flag=0;
        LED_SS=1;
        LED_MS=0;
        LED_HM=1;
        Dissect(Top_Display);
        Dissect_2(Bottom_Value);
    }

}

void interrupt isr(void) {

    asm("clrwdt");

    if (TMR1IF) {
        TMR1IF = 0;
        //  TMR1H = 0x3C;
        //  TMR1L = 0xB0;100ms

        TMR1H = 0xFE;
        TMR1L = 0x0C;// timer interrupt for 1ms
        if(Top_Display>Bottom_Value) {
            if(LED_MS_Flag==1) {
                Bottom_Value=(Sec*100)+MSec;
            } else if(LED_SeMi_Flag==1) {
                Bottom_Value=(Min*100)+Sec;
            } else if(LED_HM_Flag==1) {
                Bottom_Value=(Hour*100)+Min;
            }

        } else if(Top_Display==Bottom_Value) {

        }
        MSec++;
        if(MSec>1000) {
            MSec=0;
            Sec=Sec+1;
        }
        if(Sec>=59) {
            Sec=0;
            Min=Min+1;
        }
        if(Min>=59) {
            Min=0;
            Hour=Hour+1;
        }
        if(Hour>99) {
            Hour=0;
        }
        Display();
    }

}





} 
Void main()
 {

  while(1)
   {
Process_RUN_MODE();
  }

}

void Dissect_2(unsigned int Value)              // Spliting of process value in digits form
 {
    unsigned char a,Temp;
    for(a = 4;a >= 1 ; a--)
    {

     Temp = Value%10;
     Value = Value/10;
     LEDBuffer_1[a-1] = DISPTABLE[Temp];    

    }

 }

void Dissect(unsigned int Value)            // Spliting of process value in digits form
 {
    unsigned char a,Temp;

    for(a = 8;a >= 5 ; a--)
    {
     Temp = Value%10;
     Value = Value/10;
     LEDBuffer_1[a-1] = DISPTABLE[Temp];    

    }

 }
```

Comment: unsigned int b = Top_Display / 100; unsigned int c = Top_Display - b*100; and then b and c are your two split variables.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the fact that the target is a microcontroller has no bearing on the fact it's a pure programming question.

Comment: Here is my code. Top Display shows Set value and Bottom Display shows process value. I have variable Msec, Sec,Min,Hour  which is independently running.now bottom value should display Min and sec increment. My question how to split and display bottom one

Answer (score 3):

> 1) variable declaration. I have declare variable unsigned int Top_Display=0; if assign Top_Display=0123 display shows 0083 if assign Top_Display=123 display shows 0123 Some of the variable it take properly and some are not. if i assign value Top_Display=0129 it gives error digit is out of range.

In C and many other programming languages, **leading zero indicates an [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) number**.

```
printf("%d\n", 010);

8
```

As there is no '8' or '9' in a well-formed octal number, you get an error at compile time.  Your constant `0123` is decimal 83, and that's probably not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

> Here 1234 variable used for timing application.Assume 1234 where 12 M
>   and 34 Sec. Can some one suggest me how to do it.

```
    void main()
    {
      unsigned int min,sec,Top_Display=1234;

       min = Top_Display/100; 
       sec = Top_Display%100;

    }
// Assumptions: it willalways be a 4 digit number/valid number/
```